# Unity 2D Spinning Platform With Physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, 2d, physics

In Unity, I want to create a platform that rotates like a propeller. When it hits an object, I want that object to go flying in a logical direction. If I just update the object's rotation every frame, the object tends to stick to the platform and pass through it at higher speeds. I'm thinking that Unity's physics would be the best solution - how can I rotate the platform at a constant speed such that it can do what I want? In addition, how can I start and stop the spinning without it speeding up or slowing down? I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to incorporate Unity's physics into your platform behaviour, but don't want to deal with adding force/torque to change its rotational speed, consider using [`Rigidbody.angularVelocity`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html). With this, you can also start and stop the rotation instantly (use `FixedUpdate()` when you're working with a `RigidBody`).

So your code may look like:

```cs
Vector3 activeVelocity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
bool isStopped = false;
RigidBody rBody;

void Start() {
    rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (!isStopped){
        rBody.angularVelocity = activeVelocity;
    }
    else{
        rBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}

public void ActivateRotation() {
    isStopped = false;
}

public void FreezeRotation() {
    isStopped = true;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.